# How to write a generic method that takes any java object and convert it into a json string

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I was writing some ajax controllers for my spring mvc based application. Now in a single class, I have three methods for three separate ajax call handlers with same root url (That is why I placed them inside a single class). Now in each of the controller I have to return a Json(stringified) and I am using Object Mapper to achieve it. But when I saw that the all three methods look exactly similar apart from the argument type, it struck me that whether there is way to make the code more elegant.

### Methods called by ajax controllers

```
private String translateGetABCResponseToString(ABC response) {
        try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(response);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            throw new ValidationException(ex);
        }
    }

private String translateGetDEFResponseToString(DEF response) {
            try {
                return mapper.writeValueAsString(response);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
                throw new ValidationException(ex);
            }
        }

private String translateGetXYZResponseToString(XYZ response) {
            try {
                return mapper.writeValueAsString(response);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
                throw new ValidationException(ex);
            }
        }
```

---

Now, What I want is that is there a way to make a single method as all three methods are essentially doing the same thing.

Comment: Well, yes. Just take a common superclass or interface as argument (ultimately, java.lang.Object), just like ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString does: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValueAsString(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create complex JSON from a java object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604150/create-complex-json-from-a-java-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Object`:

```
private String translateObjectToString(Object obj) {
    try {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
        throw new ValidationException(ex);
    }
}
```

Mapper doesn't care what you give it. It will all work just fine.

Comment: Hi, I find this, the easiest way, but I am concerned about, if there is any sort of Security issue using `Object` as the parameter.

Comment: @SaurabhGupta there is no security issue I can think of. What kind of problem are you worried about?